# How to Replace Columns in Excel with Another Column header?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data in Excel which looks like this:

[image: data]

How to replace the answer column with the header of the same value as in the same row? For example, 600 was present in the column C , so the answer is replaced with C, and so on. The final output looks like this:

[image: final output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `INDEX()` function with `MATCH()`. Try-

```
=INDEX($B$2:$E$2,1,MATCH(F3,B3:E3,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it will work million of rows. Match function will detect column of answer value. Then INDEX function will return desired result from heading row. Do few google search about index and match function. Also if it helps then tick mark and the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but some on rows it shows this error : Value is not available. Pls see this screenshot : https://i.postimg.cc/5tv4YmQr/image.png

Comment: which is shown as #N/A , how to fix this ?

Comment: You have to use IFERROR like `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$E$2,1,MATCH(F3,B3:E3,0)),"")`.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this question from two different people posed in two different ways in the last two days.

Please see https://superuser.com/questions/1737814/how-to-match-values-in-column-a-with-values-in-columns-b-c-or-d-and-return-the/1738006#1738006 for more solutions including dynamic arrays.